# Custom ID when registering Fitbit

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, callback, fitbit

For my system, my users have their own unique ID (`participant_id`) that I've provided them.

I have a flask server that registers my users with Fitbit.

```
@app.route('/fitbit_authorize')
def homepage(): #probably need to send participant_id here
    return '<a href="%s">Authenticate with fitbit</a>' % FITBIT_AUTHORIZATION_URL
```

Fitbit sends a post request regarding the successfulness of my participant registration to the following where I get their user access/refresh tokens for oauth:

```
@app.route('/fitbit_callback')
def fitbit_callback():
    error = request.args.get('error', '')
    if error:
        return "Error: " + error
    state = request.args.get('state', '')
    code = request.args.get('code')
    token = fitbit_access.get_full_token(code)
```

I was wondering how can I retrieve the authorizer's original ID (`participant_id`) in the callback. Is there anyway for me to pass additional information in the fitbit authorization process or what would be the best way for me to retrieve their `participant_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question.

Oauth2 allows for you to include state information in the authorization request---You can include the `participant_id` in the state parameter: https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/oauth2/

> *state*: Provides any state that might be useful to your application
>   when the user is redirected back to your application. This parameter
>   will be added to the redirect URI exactly as your application
>   specifies. Fitbit strongly recommend including an anti-forgery token
>   in this parameter and confirming its value in the redirect to mitigate
>   against cross-site request forgery (CSRF).

In addition to providing the participant_id, you should provide an anti-forgery token to help fight CSRF.